# why i can acces data from end of computer stack c#

Tags: c#, memory, stack

In c# int is value type and stores in stack. Stack works as LIFO so i can't acces data from the end or middle

```
 static void Main() {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine(c);
      }
```

Why i can print `a` variable first if it is in the end of the stack

Comment: [**The stack is an implementation detail**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one), all you really need to understand is its behaviour. But the real answer lies in the fact that the stack is made of entire *stack frames*, which contain all the local variables for a function call, it's not a series of single variables.

Answer (score 0):

> Why i can print a variable first if it is in the end of the stack

Because there’s always a pointer to the end of the stack, and compiler knows that a is 12 bytes from this pointer.

When this method returns the stack pointer will be decremented and these int values will be beyond the end of the stack.

Comment: 1) What if i want print only `b` variable which is in the middle of stack. Why i can print it without deleting `c` variable ?  2) What means  "int values will be beyond the end of the stack.". Where this variables will be moved?

Comment: @ZeroBug Nothing is moved anywhere, the stack pointer is decremented, which means that *all* the local variables are not logically part of the stack anymore and can be deleted or overwritten

Comment: And you can read and write at any address, not just at the end.